$\mu(H)=0$ for every half plane $H$, implies the measure $\mu=0$?
A set $H$ is called a half plane if $H$ is of the form $H=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: ax+by\leq c\}$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$.

Let $\mu$ be a finite complex Borel measure on $\mathbb R^2$. If $\mu(H)=0$ for every half plane $H$. Can we conclude that the measure $\mu=0$?

My simple observations:

We can assume $\mu$ is real valued.
Let $\chi_H$ be the indicator function on $H$, we can deduce that for every half plane $H$, the convolution $$\chi_H*\mu(z)=0.$$

